# metasploit couldnt find my new created modules

Tags: metasploit

I created a new folder call `~/.msf6/modules/auxiliary/scanner/mssql` first, and then I created a new ruby file call ihaz_sql.rb
and here is the code

```
require 'msf/core'

class MetasploitModule < Msf::Auxiliary 
  include Msf::Exploit::Remote::MSSQL
  include Msf::Auxiliary::Scanner

  def initialize
    super(
      'Name' => 'I HAZ SQL Utility',
      'Version' => '$Revision: 7243 $',
      'Description' => 'This just prints some funny stuff.',
      'Author' => 'TESTs security',
      'License' => MSF_LICENSE
    )

    deregister_options('RPORT', 'PHOST')
  end

  def run_host(ip)
    begin
      puts 'I HAZ SQL!!!!'
    end
  end
end
```

and then I open metasploit using `msfconsole`

and do `search ihaz` and `search ihaz_sql`, but all of above results shows
`[-] No results from search`

here is the tutorial I am following https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/building-module/

Answer (score 0):

I myself am pretty new to Metasploit, so this answer may or may not help you.

I came across such an issue before, the "fix" for it was just to run the command:
`use <full pathname to the ruby script>`. For example, after adding a `~/.msf6/modules/exploits/cgi/webapps/example.rb` ruby script file, run the `updatedb` command and directly run the `use exploit/cgi/webapps/example.rb` command to use the exploit.

Hope this solves your issue.